# log4net LogicalThreadContext on Middleware NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, log4net

I'm using log4net on a Net Core 3.1 Web API. On my Controller I set a property on LogicalThreadContext, like this:

```
LogicalThreadContext.Properties["userId"] = "userId";
```

In my flow (Controller->Service->Repositories) when I log, I get the `userId` in all my logs. But I also have a Middleware to log something at the end of the request. When I log in the Middleware I get null from `LogicalThreadContext.Properties["userId"]`

```
var userId = LogicalThreadContext.Properties["userId"]; //userId = null
```

What am I missing. Why LogicalThreadContext properties are null in the Middleware?

Comment: What does the middleware look like? As of netstandard1.3 log4net LogicalThreadContextStacks uses AsyncLocal and it may not play nicely with however the middleware is handled.  I'd a scoped instance attached to your IoC (if your IoC is able to inject into the middleware) or HttpContext with HttpContext injected into your middleware.

Comment: Hi @DavidL, thanks for reply. The middleware is pretty simple just 2 line: await _next(context); and Log.Info("text"). You say, not using log4net LogicalThreadContext, instead using some scoped (IoC) object with the information that I need?

Comment: That would be my recommendation. That way you can change logging frameworks down the road if need be as well.